# wp_delete_user with username

Tags: functions, users

`wp_delete_user()` function requires user ID and [optional] reassign ID if the content is to be reassigned to another user.

All users' user names are also unique as WP doesn't allow duplicate user names. If I know username, is there no way with just one PHP/mysqli query I can delete the user instead of run one query to find ID of that user first and then tell wordpress to delete that user ?

Comment: Anyhow this will be a complex MySQL query because you also have to delete user meta and to reassign all posts to another user. My opinion is to stay with finding out the user ID and `wp_delete_user( $ID_to_delete, $reassign_posts_to_diff_ID )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this with only one query. But to be honest - deleting user takes more than one query itself...

You shouldn’t use custom SQL for that, because there are many things you could break this way... Always use WP functions, if they exists (what if some plugin logs every deleted user, or what if some other action is needed, etc.)

You can use [`get_user_by`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/) to achieve that. Here's the example:

```
$user = get_user_by( 'login', 'john' );
if ( $user ) { // get_user_by can return false, if no such user exists
    wp_delete_user( $user->ID );
}
```

The fields you can get user by are: `ID` | `slug` | `email` | `login`.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice to use WordPress function wp_delete_user() as it will delete user meta as well by running multiple queries on WordPress Database.

Check WordPress codex for more info: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_user/

Also it's easy to get user id and then delete user by adding something like

```
    $user = get_userdatabylogin('loginname');
    if($user){
        //delete user if exists
        wp_delete_user($user->ID);
    }
```

Or Else, You have to run multiple queries of generate a very complex query to properly remove user from WordPress database

Comment: Your answer satisfies what I asked but I accepted @krzysiek's answer as your function works on login name whereas Krzysiek's get_user_by works for email etc so opens more flexibility in dealing with the user. Sorry I have no reputation to upvote too for your efforts this time.

Comment: Warning: `get_userdatabylogin` is now deprecated.